# Enumerate blob names in Azure Data Factory v2

Tags: azure-data-factory

I need to enumerate all the blob names that sit in an Azure Blobs container and dump the list to a file in another blob storage.

The part that I cannot master is the enumeration.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Get metadata activity is what you want.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity

1. Please use childItems to get all the files. And then use a foreach to iterate the childItems
   [image]
2. Inside the for each activity, you may want to check if each item is a file. You could use if activity and the following expression. 
   [image]
3. Then in the "If true" activity, assume you want to copy data, you could use @item().name to get each of your file name. 
   [image]

You could find more documentations with this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/quickstart-create-data-factory-portal).

Comment: Thanks, I am using the Author & Monitoring UI. I have defined my metadata activity but still not sure how to send it output to a .csv file stored in a blob storage

Comment: could you elaborate a little bit more about your scenario? Why would you want to store it to a file?

Comment: I have millions of files that I store in a blob container but I also keep track of each item in a cosmos db database. Periodically I need to reconcile the data that is physically stored in blob container and the records kept in database. So I need a list of all blob names because I am able to read the data from database.

Comment: If you want to compare the blob name list with records in cosmos dB, you could use the output of the get metadata activity directly as following @{activity('MyGetMetadataActivity').output.childItems}. Then you don’t have to store it to a single file. But get metadata data activity has a limitation of the output: the maximum size is 1M. If you have large number of data, I am not sure whether the output will exceed 1M

Comment: And I noticed that azure blob storage has APIs to list Blobs. The other way I can come up with would be write your own custom C# code and call it with ADF custom activity.

Comment: Sorry to be a pain, I still don't understand how to use get meta activity's output in another activity, using the ADF web UI. I have defined my GetMetadataActivity but somehow I do not get how it functions

Comment: Added an example in my answer

Comment: Thank you, what next now? I need to create a sub-activity, however it seems that I need more hands on experience with adf..

Comment: You could double click the foreach activity in the UI. Then you will be navigated into the foreach. And then just drag and drop the activity you  want. Updated more pictures.