# In AzureDataFactory,Unable to configure a collection of .wav files in container as 'Dataset'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

In AzureDataFactory,Unable to configure a collection of .wav files in container as 'Dataset' . Dataset is formed by the data inside those files
My task is to iterate names of files present in a blob container and use the file name in web activity

I thought to use Lookup to store the file name collections in variable as array . But I need to connect to a dataset. While creating a dataset,
 it doesn't accept collections  of files in container as dataset. It automatically takes the data in each files(which are inside the container) as dataset.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVYwI.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chain a for each  activity after your lookup activity. Put the web activity inside into the for each activity 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-for-each-activity

Comment: yes, I even tried it, but I don't know what expression to give in ITEM section under SETTING tab in For each loop activity. I have no clue what expression to give in order to loop the file names present in the blob container

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52014916/enumerate-blob-names-in-azure-data-factory-v2 please reference this.

Comment: It worked. How did you know to add childItems in the dynamic expression

Comment: You could reference the doc of get meta data activity. And you could also use the debug button in the UI